# Lead Import is creating blank records

Tags: data-loader, leads, record

Another Admin is mass importing Leads via Dataloader. The load is working correctly, and all the records are created as expected. But for some reason, it also seems to be creating "phantom" Lead records, that have no information. I've looked into some of the records, and while it seems as though they are being created by the import, with the little info that is present, I can't figure out why.

I'm curious if anyone else has seen anything like this? Do you know what causes it? Are there steps to reduce or eliminate this?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a small sample of the csv that was used in the lead import? Have you put a debug log on during the import? This way you can check if the repeated empty records are due to automated processes.

Comment: @CasparHarmer because it's PII, I have been told I can't post any of the csv. I will check into the debug logs. That is something I didn't think of. thank you!

Comment: I guess what I need to see is the STRUCTURE of the leads csv, not the actual records. A couple of lines of made up data would do, as long as it follows the exact format of the original csv.

Comment: I would check for these:
1. Make sure the import process is the culprit creating these phantom records
2. While importing using CSV check the field mapping and final confirmation on  number of records being imported and see if CSV has additional blank rows that being pulled into import process causing this
3. Redesign [not supplied] logic implemented to import blank records

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some issues with your CSV file.
To avoid dealing with CVS altogether, use a data loader that works directly from [Excel](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-enabler4excel-365/) or [Google Sheets](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/installing-g-connector/).